# SQL conditions with mutually exclusive performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery, query-performance

I just replaced an SQL statement that looked like this:

```
SELECT UserID, sUserName, sFirstName + ' ' + sLastName as [Name], iSiteNumber
FROM DecimalUsers left join dbo.CustomerSitePermissions on  UserID = iUserID
WHERE 
    (cast(iSiteNumber as nvarchar(50)) like '%' + @query + '%' and (iPermissionIndex = 2 or iPermissionIndex = 0) and (bPrimarySite = 'true' or UserID in
        (SELECT top 1 iUserID FROM CustomerSitePermissions where iUserID not in
        (SELECT iUserID FROM CustomerSitePermissions WHERE bPrimarySite = 'true'))))
    OR CAST(sUserName as NVARCHAR(50)) LIKE @query + '%'
    OR CAST(sFirstName as NVARCHAR(50)) LIKE @query + '%'
    OR CAST(sLastName as NVARCHAR(50)) LIKE @query + '%';
```

It ran very slowly (around 15 seconds per query). Maybe it's that first part of the `WHERE` statement with the ugly nested queries. Sure enough, removing it knocks the time down to under a second. Case closed!

### OR IS IT?

Not only did the query speed up when you removed the first where condition, but also if you removed all the other ones. Checking `sUserName`, `sFirstName`, and `sLastName`, but **not** `iSiteNumber` ran in under one second. Likewise, checking `iSiteNumber`, but **not** `sUserName`, `sFirstName`, or `sLastName` also ran in under a second. The query was only slow if the `iSiteNumber` check and *any other check* (didn't matter which one or how many) was left in.

Something about this query is slower than the sum of its parts. Why?

Comment: Faster query execution, but different result? This site number check actually looks overly complicated and can probably be replaced with some Windowed Aggregates. And the Left join is probably an Inner join due to the Where-condition. Check the plans of the optimizer, it probably changed when switching conditions.

Comment: Your casts to NVarchar have every potential of creating a non-sargable query (and thus slow), regardless of indexing.

Comment: As it happens, none of these columns are indexed. I'm mostly trying understand how these two fast(ish) queries, when joined by an `OR`, could become one very slow query.

Answer (score 1):

Firt, however, be sure you have proper index  then

In your iSiteNumber 
You are using multiple subselect for in clause,   this force the db engine for repeated  access  to data  ..

for the others part  each OR clause mean a repeated  access to date

could be that  you can rewrite you query avoiding these tecnique

eg instead of  the not in  for where bPrimarySite = 'true'

```
  ( SELECT top 1 iUserID 
        FROM CustomerSitePermissions where iUserID not in
        (SELECT iUserID 
          FROM CustomerSitePermissions WHERE bPrimarySite = 'true'
    )
  )
```

you could use a inner join  for the inverted  logical query  or a simplified  query eg:

```
  ( SELECT top 1 iUserID 
    FROM CustomerSitePermissions where 
    bPrimarySite = 'false'
  )
```

and you could try to rewrite you query for avoid the upper subselect for an IN clause and use a inner join  .. if is possible.

*These suggestion can be useful or not depending by the real  logic and result you really need*

Comment: This is very helpful, but I still can't figure out the mutual exclusivity. If I take the slowest part (probably the `iSiteNumber` check) and multiply it by four, it should still be *much* slower than 15 seconds. Something about this query is slower than the sum of it's parts.

Comment: this is tipical  ..  you could take a look at your explain plan  for get some info  about how the db engine is involved  by the query.. then you should also take a look at mysql chaper for query optimizer .. in this doc there are several aspect that can explain why you have  the performace  you noted .. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-optimization.html